# D3 Zoom & Pan - How to enable zooming & panning anywhere on the chart and restrict showing circle within the range while panning & zooming

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm trying to develop a timeline chart using `D3` libary with `zoom` and `pan` options. Here is the jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/avavzgLy/.

I'm able to zoom and pan only when I hover on x axis ticks or over `Circles` in the chart. How can I allow zooming and panning by hovering anywhere on the chart. Also while zooming/panning, the circles inside chart is still getting displayed when it reaches x axis domain range and gets disappeared only when it reaches svg width.

Comment: Stick a rect element in under (or even over) everything and use that to catch zoom/pan events on otherwise empty areas.

Answer (score 0):

I addressed the above mentioned issues by using [ClipPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) `SVG`element. Updated working jsfiddle link - https://jsfiddle.net/avavzgLy/1/